# How to safely copy Dropbox/.dropbox and Dropbox/.dropbox.cache?

Tags: dropbox

I have a large Dropbox/ directory and I have copied it to a new computer which I have not linked to my Dropbox account.  Before linking, should I do anything to the Dropbox/.dropbox and Dropbox/.dropbox.cache directories?  What are their purpose, is it safe to use the two directories created on another computer?

Comment: Just install Dropbox on the new machine, log in. It will sync.